# JUnit Tests not showing in Sonar-Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, sonarqube

**This is my sonar.properties file**

```
sonar.host.url=https://sonar.cloud.health.ge.com/
sonar.projectKey=ils
sonar.projectName=ILS
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.sources=library/core
sonar.java.binaries=library/core/target/classes
sonar.exclusions=library/core/target/**/*, library/core/src/test/**/*
sonar.tests=library/core/src/test/
sonar.java.test.libraries=library/core/target/test-classes/

> sonar.junit.reportsPath=library/core/target/surefire-reports/CalculatorTest.xml
// test cases are generated fine but sonarqube is not taking the junit reports in the pipeline

sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=library/core/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
```

> I have pushed the testreports manually and
> Below is the unit-test command in Jenkins File

```
unitTestCommand          = 'cd library/core && mvn test && mvn surefire-report:report'
unitTestReportDir        = 'library/core/target/site'
arch                     = 'hc-eu-west-aws-artifactory.cloud.health.ge.com/docker-eis-all/build-tools-eis-repo:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jacoco maven plugin (https://www.jacoco.org/) for generate report with coverage.

```
unitTestCommand          = 'cd library/core && mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report && mvn surefire-report:report'
```

Comment: ISSUE RESOLVED: 
There was an issue in the path, sonar.junit.reportsPath should point to a directory rather than a specific file: 
```sonar.junit.reportsPath=library/core/target/surefire-reports/
```

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE RESOLVED:**
There was an issue in the path, sonar.junit.reportsPath should point to a directory rather than a specific file:

```
sonar.junit.reportsPath=library/core/target/surefire-reports/
```